# Getting around and parking in Bryce Canyon when the shuttle is not operating

Tags: usa, national-parks, utah

[This page](https://www.nps.gov/brca/planyourvisit/shuttle.htm) seems to imply that there is no shuttle service in Bryce in December. So I assume the only way to get to trailheads for a group of people is by car. However, I was unable to find any information about parking on the official website, and I don't see any parking lots in Google Maps. Where can one park in Bryce Canyon (say, in the walking distance of the Sunset Point)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sunset Point (and all the other named points in Bryce) all have parking lots of various sizes, as well as a well paved Rim Trail that connects all of them.  In particular, Sunset Point's parking lot [probably fits 60-70 cars](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.6234048,-112.1676311,421m/data=!3m1!1e3).